# Mensagem de sucesso depois de enviar mensagem por formulário

Tags: php, html, formulário

Quero que depois que preenchido o formulário e clicado no botão "enviar" apareça uma mensagem informando que o conteúdo foi enviado com sucesso, na mesma página!

Vou colocar o meu código, agradeço a ajuda.

```html
                            <div class="contact_form_container">
                                <form method="post" action="email.php" class="contact_form">
                                    <div class="row contact_form_row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Nome" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="contact_input" placeholder="e-mail" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <input id="assunto" name="assunto" type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Assunto" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <textarea id="msg" class="contact_input contact_textarea" name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button id="enviar" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" onClick="Enviar();" class="contact_button">ENVIAR</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

e o php, que está sendo direcionado para outra página

```php
<?php

$para="julianyfatoretto@gmail.com";
$subject="Contato pelo site";   

$nome= $_REQUEST['nome'];
$email= $_REQUEST['email'];
$assunto= $_REQUEST['assunto'];
$msg= $_REQUEST['mensagem'];

$enviar="<strong>Mensagem de contato</strong><br><br>";
$enviar.="<br><strong>Nome: </strong> $nome";
$enviar.="<br><strong>email: </strong> $email";
$enviar.="<br><strong>Assunto: </strong> $assunto";
$enviar.="<br><strong>Mensagem: </strong> $msg";

$header="Content-Type: text/html; charset- utf-8\n";
$header.="From: $email Replay-to: $email\n";


$mail = mail($nome,$email,$assunto,$msg);
if($mail){
    echo("Enviado com sucesso!");
}else{
    echo("Erro!");
}

?>
```

Comment: Você pode fazer isso com `AJAX`.

Comment: use **AJAX** para isso, e para fica melhor legível troque **$_REQUEST** por **$_POST**

Answer (score 2):

Olá @JulianyGarcia, seja bem-vinda ao StackOverflowPT, há **"n"** formas de fazer isso, usando ajax, e fazendo post diretamente na página.

Eu recomendaria você a estudar Javascript, que é uma linguagem client-side. Acredito que usar [ajax](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3585/ajax-basico-introducao.aspx), é uma maneira melhor de enviar os dados, pois evita o recarregamento da página desnecessariamente.

É importante também considerar a validação do formulário, para que ele não chegue incompleto, e validar o e-mail para que a função `email()` não retorne um erro.

Eu recomendaria ao invés de utilizar a função mail, usar uma biblioteca tipo [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), assim você não corre risco de que seu formulário pare de funcionar, caso seu servidor desative a função por questões de segurança.

Vou apresentar duas soluções, e você veja qual prefere, para a primeira forma vou colocar uma condicional na página, e todo o conteúdo na mesma página:

**1) SOLUÇÃO (Método POST básico):**

Salve sua página como **contato.php** e coloque uma condição de POST:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
   $err= false;
   if($_POST['nome'] == ""){
    $err = true;
     echo " - O nome precisa ser preenchido.<br>";
   }
   if(($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) || !$_POST['email']){
    $err = true;
     echo " - preencha um email válido.<br>";
   }
 if ($_POST['assunto'] == ""){
    $err = true;
     echo " - preencha o assunto.<br>";
 }
  if ($_POST['mensagem'] == ""){
     $err = true;
     echo " - preencha sua mensagem.<br>";
  }
  if (!$err) {
     $para="julianyfatoretto@gmail.com";
     $subject="Contato pelo site";   

     $nome= $_POST['nome'];
     $email= $_POST['email'];
     $assunto= $_POST['assunto'];
     $msg= $_POST['mensagem'];

     $enviar="<strong>Mensagem de contato</strong><br><br>";
     $enviar.="<br><strong>Nome: </strong> $nome";
     $enviar.="<br><strong>email: </strong> $email";
     $enviar.="<br><strong>Assunto: </strong> $assunto";
     $enviar.="<br><strong>Mensagem: </strong> $msg";

     $header="Content-Type: text/html; charset- utf-8\n";
     $header.="From: $email Replay-to: $email\n";

     $mail = mail($nome,$email,$assunto,$msg);
     if ($mail) {
        echo "<p>Enviado com sucesso!</p>";
     } else {
        $err = true;
        echo "<p>Ocorreu um erro no servidor</p>";
     }
  }
} else {
   echo "<p>Por favor, preencha o formulário abaixo:</p>";
}

?>

 <div class="contact_form_container">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>" class="contact_form">
        <div class="row contact_form_row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Nome" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="contact_input" placeholder="e-mail" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                <input id="assunto" name="assunto" type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Assunto" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                <textarea id="msg" class="contact_input contact_textarea" name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="enviar" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="contact_button">ENVIAR</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**2) SOLUÇÃO (método ajax):**

Iremos criar um método de envio (há pessoas que gostam de utilizar uma biblioteca chamada [jquery](https://jquery.com/), mas eu prefiro utilizar javascript puro, ES5 ou ES6).

Ao submeter o formulário, você continuará na página e enviará sincronamente os dados por ajax no formato json, assim que o php tratar isso no lado servidor (server-side), você receberá no escopo do seu método o retorno no formato que você solicitou no seu xhr.responseType, no caso um json:

```
    <script>

     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      //depois que o dom for lido


        function sendForm() {

           var resultBox = document.querySelector('#message');

            //AQUI VOCÊ RECEBE OS DADOS DO SITE DOIS
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.response.status) {
                      resultBox.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">' + xhr.response.message + '</div>';
                    //sucesso, você obterá retorno de um JSON com dados 

                 } else {
                  if(xhr.response.message) {
                  resultBox.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + xhr.response.message  + '</div>';
                   } else {
 resultBox.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + xhr.statusText + '</div>';
                   }
                }
            }
        }
       var button = document.getElementById('enviar'),
           input_nome = document.querySelector('#nome'),
           input_email = document.querySelector('#email'),
           input_assunto = document.querySelector('#assunto'),
           input_mensagem = document.querySelector('#msg'),
           actionSend = function() {

                    var url = 'outra-pagina.php',
                        dados = {
                           nome: input_nome.value,
                           email: input_email.value,
                           assunto: input_assunto.value,
                           mensagem: input_mensagem.value,
                        };
                     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

                     xhr.open("POST", url + '?rnd='+randomNum, false);
                     xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                     xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dados));
                     xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", sendForm, false);
             }
              button.addEventListener("click", actionSend, false); 


    });

    </script>
```

**Coloque a cima do form:**

```
<div id="message">Por favor, preencha o formulário:</div>
```

E remova o método `Enviar()` do seu botão de submissão. Mude o type para **button**.

Ou se preferir manter **submit**, no método de click (`actionSend`), acrescente `event.preventDefault()` para que a página não seja recarregada e acrescente o parâmetro event no método `actionSend`, ficaria assim: `function actionSend(event) { ... }`

Na outra página: **outra-pagina.php**, você recebe os dados e responde em json:

```
 <?php

 $arr = array();

  if ($_POST) {
       $status = true;
       if ($_POST['nome'] == "") {
          $status = false;
          $arr[] = " - O nome precisa ser preenchido.";
       }
       if (($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) || !$_POST['email']){
          $status = false;
          $arr[] = " - preencha um email válido.";
       }
     if ($_POST['assunto'] == ""){
         $status = false;
         $arr[] = " - preencha o assunto.";
     }
      if ($_POST['mensagem'] == ""){
         $status = false;
         $arr[] = " - preencha sua mensagem.";
      }
      if ($status) {
         $para="julianyfatoretto@gmail.com";
         $subject="Contato pelo site";   

         $nome= $_POST['nome'];
         $email= $_POST['email'];
         $assunto= $_POST['assunto'];
         $msg= $_POST['mensagem'];

         $enviar="<strong>Mensagem de contato</strong><br><br>";
         $enviar.="<br><strong>Nome: </strong> $nome";
         $enviar.="<br><strong>email: </strong> $email";
         $enviar.="<br><strong>Assunto: </strong> $assunto";
         $enviar.="<br><strong>Mensagem: </strong> $msg";

         $header="Content-Type: text/html; charset- utf-8\n";
         $header.="From: $email Replay-to: $email\n";

         $mail = mail($nome,$email,$assunto,$msg);
         if ($mail) {
            $status = true;
            $message = "Enviado com sucesso!";
         } else {
            $status = false;
            $message = "Ocorreu um erro no servidor";
         }
      }
    } else {
        $message = "Por favor, preencha o formulário abaixo:";
    }

    $result = array(
     'message' => $message,
     'status' => $status
    );
    if(!$status && is_array($arr) && count($arr) > 0) {
       $msg = implode('<br>', $arr);
       $result['message'] = $msg;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma de resposta do Ivan Ferrer é a correta, realmente através de **AJAX** é a solução mais fácil, um padrão de mensagens que eu utilizo:

[Sweet Alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

Importe esse **JS** na sua aplicação:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

E no seu **AJAX** faça da seguinte forma:

```
swal({
    title: "Sucesso!",
    text: "Cadastro concluído com êxito",
    icon: "success",
    button: "OK"
    });
```